# How to implement sharing suggestions in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, share

I am trying to follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/app_extension_support/supporting_suggestions_in_your_app_s_share_extension) apple developer article to implement **share suggestions** in a sample iOS project.

I have followed these 3 steps exactly as described

1. Added a share extension in my app.
2. Declared support for the INSendMessageIntent intent type.
3. Donated an INSendMessageIntent in app and its share extension.

In the below screenshot, we can see sharing suggestions from Messages app and one other app.

[image: Sharing suggestions highlighted]

### The problem

Although I have followed all the steps as described in the article, my sample app is not showing as a suggested conversation when i try to share something.

### **Sample code**

You can find the sample project on [Github](https://github.com/AwaisFayyaz/iOS-share-suggestions-sample)

What am I missing here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have run your project but it is showing the app while sharing some items.

Comment: I have updated my image and highlighted the 'suggestions'. I want my app to show as one of the option in that suggestions box highlighted in black.

Comment: According to apple article linked above, these are called sharing suggestions and this article discusses how to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1-** First you must add your app in suggestions list from the "More" Options. ( Only if you are not seeing your app in apps row in the share sheet )

**2-** **Code Problem:** You must provide a not nil image inside intent:

```
INImage(named: "Image Name") // Won't work if image not exists.
```

Problem:
[image]

Or, Skip Image like this to make it work:

```
INImage(named: "") // Tested and working
```

One Interesting test, When image name doesn't have space, it works even if image doesn't exists:

```
INImage(named: "ImageName") // Tested and working
```

You can see the working example here: [Github](https://github.com/m-afham/iOS-share-suggestions-sample)

Working:

[image]

Comment: You are right. Since `interaction.donate(completion...)` returned success, I was thinking that there is no problem with the donation of intent. When I used an image name with no space, it worked! Thanks

Comment: But that space thing is weird

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz You're welcome. I'm glad to help you.